# Conversão de ponteiros para função para ponteiros void*

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro, conversão-de-tipo, void

Recentemente, eu estava tentando resolver um problema em um programa meu em C e, por acaso, me deparei com algumas respostas da Stack Overflow em inglês nas quais se afirmava que a conversão de um ponteiro para função para um ponteiro void* é ilegal em C.

O meu inglês não é lá grande coisa e as respostas que eu visitei são antigas, por essa razão, não estou certo de ter entendido a informação direito ou se as respostas ficaram desatualizadas com o C11. De todo o modo, deixo os links [c-cast-void-pointer-to-function-pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696918/c-cast-void-pointer-to-function-pointer) e [c-function-pointer-casting-to-void-pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579835/c-function-pointer-casting-to-void-pointer)

Mas se eu entendi direito, isso, no meu caso, é particularmente preocupante porque a verdade é que eu acho essa conversão extremamente prática e mais de um vez andei convertendo `void*` para ponteiros como `int (*f)(int, int)`.

Para não ficar muito abstrato, um exemplo desse tipo de conversão abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}

int main(){
    void* foo = &sum;
    int (*f)(int, int) = foo;
    printf("Esta soma e ilegal? Soma = %d\n", f(10, 8));
    return 0;
}
```

E não é apenas preocupante, é esquisito também já que o código acima compila e funciona perfeitamente no DevC++, CodeBlocks e VS2019, na minha máquina com o Windows 10.

Com base nisso, a minha pergunta é: a conversão de ponteiro `void*` para ponteiro para função é, de fato, não permitida pelo C padrão e o fato de o código acima funcionar na minha máquina não é garantia de que ele vá funcionar em outras implementações ou eu li errado os artigos e a conversão é permitida pelo C padrão?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É permitido fazer isto de acordo com o padrão, só não é obrigatório, então alguns compiladores podem deixar ou não e podem inclusive deixar só onde faça sentido. Mesmo que o compilador deixe pode não faz sentido, ou pode causar problemas em certas situações. Lembro sempre:

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

[Tem compilador que não aceita](https://ideone.com/x1ND5G). Mas [depende de configuração](https://ideone.com/yPMSYT). Mas olha [que beleza quando a assinatura não é compatível](https://ideone.com/gG1e3L).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int main() {
    void* foo = &sum;
    int (*f)(int, long long) = foo;
    printf("Esta soma e ilegal? Soma = %d\n", f(10, 1000000000000L));
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/FunctionVoidPointer.c).

Não é que o `void *` deixa isto acontecer, é que se o compilador deixa alguma coisa irregular passar ele deixa outras, ele é mais inseguro do que os outros. Tem motivo para usar compiladores com regras mais frouxas, mas na maioria das vezes você preferirá usar um mais restritivo e te poupar enormes dores de cabeça.